# CRON job on Ubiquity Edge Router to Modify hosts File

Tags: linux, router, cron, hosts

I am trying to setup a cron job on my Ubiquity Edge Router that will modify the hosts file once in the morning and once at night on weekdays, to block various websites from 8AM - 7PM M-F.

**I have created 2 shell scripts:**

```
/config/scripts/set-blocking-hosts.sh
/config/scripts/set-default-hosts.sh
```

**Each of these has 2 lines:**

```
cp /etc/hosts.blocking /etc/hosts
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Note that the first line with the cp command is different in each script, to copy the appropriate file (hosts.default or hosts.blocking)

If I ssh into the router and run these scripts directly, they do exactly what I want and work perfectly.

I am having trouble getting these to run on schedule using cron.

**Here are my cron entries:**

```
0 8 * * 1-5 /config/scripts/set-blocking-hosts.sh
0 19 * * 1-5 /config/scripts/set-default-hosts.sh
```

So far I have tried adding these entries using `crontab -e` and `sudo crontab -e` and neither seems to be working.

I looked for a log file in `/var/log` but I couldn't find anything relevant.

If I run this command, `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep` I get the following result, suggesting cron is running.

```
root     490     1     0 Oct24 ?     00:00:09 /usr/sbin/cron
```

I am not sure where I am supposed to put the cron entries in order for the jobs to run or if I need to reboot the router, or if something is turned off somewhere, or if this sort of thing is not supported on the router.

Disclaimer, I am not a systems guy or linux guy, so most of this I've figured out through research and trial and error.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

First, this was achieved using `sudo crontab -e` though it might also work using crontab -e from the logged in user as well -- I just don't know if there would be a permission issue.

Second, the cron entries needed to be modified to include a leading "sh" as shown below:

```
0 8 * * 1-5 sh /config/scripts/set-blocking-hosts.sh
0 19 * * 1-5 sh /config/scripts/set-default-hosts.sh
```

Lastly, and this is likely isolated to me -- I had changed the timezone on my router from UTC to PST and had not rebooted.  While `date` would show local time as PST, I think `cron` was still running based on UTC -- perhaps if I had restarted `cron`, I would not have needed a router reboot.